# Corona SDK network.request not triggering

Tags: lua, coronasdk, qr-code

I'm using the qrscanner plugin in Corona SDK to scan a QR code and perform only 2 functions. First it checks a bool value in the DB and if the value is 0 it should display a message and change it to 1.

The first network call works and updates the test in the app, but the second network call does not return anything. The code if very basic as it's my first lua/corona script.

```
local json = require( "json" )
local function handleResponse( event )
    if not event.isError then

        local data,pos,msg= json.decode(event.response)
        print( event.response )

        if not data then
            native.showAlert('error, no response', 'no response from the server', {'OK'})
        else
            if data.checked_in == "0" then
                myText.text = "Not checked in yet.\nVehicle Detail:\nReg#\n"..data.registration.."\nMake:\n"..data.make.."\nModel:\n"..data.model.."\n"
                urx2 = "http://mydomain/index.php/checkin/"..message
                network.request( urx2, "GET", handleResponse2 )
                print('Scanned message:', message)
            else
                myText.text = "WARNING: Vehicle already checked in.\nVehicle Detail:\nReg#\n"..data.registration.."\nMake:\n"..data.make.."\nModel:\n"..data.model.."\n"
            end
        end
    else
        native.showAlert('Darn: this url is broken: '..urx, message, {'OK'})
    end
    return true
end

local function handleResponse2( event )
    if not event.isError then

        local data,pos,msg= json.decode(event.response)
        print( event.response )

        if not data then
            native.showAlert('error, no response', {'OK'})
        else
            if data.checked_in == "0" then
                myText.text = "Still not checked in, try again."
            else
                myText.text = "Successfully checked in."
            end
            sceneGroup:insert( summary )
            print(data.checked_in)
        end
    end
    return true
end

local function status_listener(message)
    urx = "http://mydomainindex.php/checkedin/"..message
    network.request( urx, "GET", handleResponse )
end

local function checkin_listener(message)
    urx = "http://mydomain/index.php/checkin/"..message
    network.request( urx, "GET", handleResponse2 )
    print('Scanned message:', message)
end
```

So everything work up to this point:

```
                if data.checked_in == "0" then
                myText.text = "Not checked in yet.\nVehicle Detail:\nReg#\n"..data.registration.."\nMake:\n"..data.make.."\nModel:\n"..data.model.."\n"
                urx2 = "http://mydomain/index.php/checkin/"..message
                network.request( urx2, "GET", handleResponse2 )
                print('Scanned message:', message)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the order you call these functions?

Comment: Is `handleResponse2` being called when you make the second call (to `urx2`)? Saying "doesn't return anything" doesn't help much. You are not checking for any errors in that method, so you may want to add another branch to print `event.response` in case there is an error.